# Erro de CROSS via localhost

Tags: angular, cors

Estou consumindo um API com angular e me dá o seguinte erro ao :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/lotes' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Origun' header is present on the requested resource.

GET http://localhost:8080/lores net::ERR_FAILED

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Renan Martins, pode fechar o tópico!

Comment: Ontem mesmo eu consegui resolver!

Comment: Renan Martins, pode sim!